# All in one solution for Oracle PL/SQL student

Tags: sql, oracle-database

I am looking for something where I can develop oracle pl/sql with the following characteristics.

-That can raise a DB (DDL) in a simple way.

- That supports PL/SQL, especially anonymous functions (I assume that all go).
- DCL statements
- I don't need TCL
- Windows preferably
- Not complex to configure please
- Free or with a trial version of at least 60 days

*It is for pure testing, if you can lift and save the database in a simple way would be great.

I have tried with oracle's own but it is a horror, and looking at the rest of the post on recommendations of environments for oracle pl/sql there is none that fits what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a expert in PL/SQL but you can try [SQL Developer](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sqldeveloper-landing.html) from Oracle
From what I see it support PL/SQL (not sure about anonymous functions), you can do most of DCL operations there, support Windows OS, free

If by TCL you mean [the language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl) the software run with java.
If you need oracle database you can take a look on [Oracle Database XE](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/xe.html)

Comment: SQL developer is able to run a database and be able to query it without anything else ? And in TCL I meant [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tcl-full-form/) @RomeoNinov

Comment: @Illidan, SQL Developer by itself do not have inside database. You need to install and run (like Oracle XE). And yes, the software need java and that's all. AFAIK it offer to download package with java inside too. Also the only think you need to configure is the connection to database.

Comment: That was just what I was looking for, an environment where I could run everything without having to connect to an external database, but I think that unfortunately with ORACLE is going to be complicated...

Comment: @Illidan, you ask for `PL/SQL` and I am not sure if any other company support it. ANd IMHO it's not so complicated, I am not DB admin but I can deal with XE and SQL Dev quite easy :)